# How to put one button to right and the other button to left in two different divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

Suppose to have two button and a want that are near. So I have this code:

```
<div class="form-inline move_down">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm move_right_component" type="submit" >NEW
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" >BACK<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

where my css code is:

```
.move_right_component{
    float: right;
}
```

the button are very far I need to put two button near. I want that the first button appear at the end of the first div and the second button apear at the start. Now at the end and start of div there are too space. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The space that you are seeing ios the default padding from bootstrap clases.

Just overwrite it:

```css
.move_right_component{
    float: right;
}

.col-6 {
    height: 30px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-inline move_down">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm move_right_component" type="submit">NEW
                  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">BACK<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would better consider the default bootstrap classes like : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#no-gutters and also https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/#notation